# GRUB booting even though I have Ubuntu uninstalled

Tags: grub2, windows-10

A while ago, I'd say 2 or 3 years ago, I didn't have a Windows 7 License, so I decided to install Ubuntu, because I'd always wanted to try Linux, and because it was free. I decided it wasn't my cup of tea, and decided I just wanted to buy a W7 license.

So, since I uninstalled Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 license-less at the time, I just went into Windows 7's `Programs and Features` menu, and uninstalled Ubuntu, and wiped the partition and conjoined it with the main one.

Now, at the time, I thought this was all I needed to do, so I didn't do FixMBR before uninstalling and deleting the partitions. Fast-forward to nowadays, I took advantage of the free update to Windows 10 from last(?) year, I've had to live with the `minimal bash-like editing is supported...` menu and pressing f11 and f12 and selecting boot drive as Windows Boot Manager every time I launch my PC.

As a separate note, if this matters to the situation, in my Disk Management window, there's a EFI partition of 100 MB in my main disk, while my C: drive is NTFS and I have a recovery partition.

Also, I forgot to mention that Fixmbr and similar commands in a recovery drive don't work.

So, I was wondering if there was any way to fix this so that my Windows boots automatically?

Comment: There's no more Ubuntu on your computer and the boot option manager of your BIOS or Windows are unrelated to Ubuntu and there off topic on AskUbuntu. It would be on topic on out sister site [SU].

Answer (score 0):

Boot your windows start a command-prompt (cmd) and write:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

reboot and verify that grub has disappeared and you are booting directly into windowa.